# Fetch fields from another objectApiName with Aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, object

I am doing the following code

```
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Opportunity">
                  <lightning:messages />
                  <lightning:inputField fieldName="Point_Code__c" />
                  <lightning:inputField fieldName="Opportunity.Contact__r.FirstName" />
                  <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

At the moment it only shows me the Point_Code__c because that field is in Opportunity but the FirstName does not show anything

The problem is that I think SalesForce doesn't like to use "Contact__r.FirstName".
My question is, how can I call a reference on that field to bring fields from "Contact" object to "Opportunity"

looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot  reference relationships in lightning input fields, from the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation):

> The fields specified must be associated with only one object.